# How can I connect two PCs via a third IP address?

Tags: networking, routing

Assume that PC A, IP `10.49.1.1` wants to send a packet over IP address `10.70.70.1` to PC B, IP `10.49.1.8`. PC B receives the packet and sends it back over `10.70.70.1` to PC A. Both PCs are connected via a switch. It's important that PC A is connected via `10.70.70.1` with PC B.

How can I setup PC A (Linux) to route the packet to PC B and vice versa?

Comment: What do you mean with "over IP address 10.70.70.1"?

Comment: The application on PC A and PC B shall send and receive packets on `10.70.70.1`. In detail: PC A is a NTP-Client, PC B is NTP-Server. PC B can not have the IP-Address `10.70.70.1`, therefore, I thought routing via `10.70.70.1`, like `10.49.1.1` <-> `10.70.70.1`<-> `10.49.1.8`, is possible or not?

Comment: And what do you mean with "send and receive packets on 10.70.70.1". Why can't A and B communicate directly? We need more information.

Comment: Because, the requirement say: PC A is connect to PC B via switch on `10.70.70.1`.

Comment: And what does "via switch on 10.70.70.1" mean? Do you have a managed switch that has that ip?

Comment: No, the switch can not manage `10.70.70.1`. I thought, I can setup one (static) route  from `10.49.1.1` to `10.70.70.1` and another (static) route from `10.70.70.1` to `10.49.1.8` on PC A to full fill the requirement, that the application on PC A send a NTP packets via `10.70.70.1`.

Comment: I simply don't get the problem. You want traffic from A to B routed over 10.70.70.1, yet A and B are connected to a switch... `10.49.1.1` and `.8` are mutually on-link, so by default the kernel wouldn't even consider sending traffic to a router. Assigning addresses such as `10.49.1.1/32` (note the subnet mask) and establishing a host route _might_ help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Networking doesn't work the way you think it works. IP address are assigned to *network interfaces*, not PCs, and not programs. LAN segements (connected via a switch) must have a common IP prefix.

So you can have situation like this:

```
+------------------------+   +-----------+  
|          PC A          |   |   PC B    |
|                        |   |           |
| eth1         eth0      |   | eth0      |
| 10.70.70.1   10.49.1.1 |   | 10.49.1.8 |
+------------------------+   +-----------+
    |             |                |
----+             +----------------+
switch                  switch
10.70.70.0/24           10.49.1.0/24
```

In that case, PC A can send packets to PC B using `10.49.1.8`, and PC B can send packets to PC A using `10.49.1.1` as destination. If PC B has a route like

```
 ip route add 10.70.70.0/24 dev eth0 via 10.49.1.1
```

then PC B will send all packet to `10.70.70.*` first to PC A, and in particular it will reach PC A under `10.70.70.1` *if some application is bound on all network interfaces, or on this particular interface*.

Is that what you wanted?

If not, please explain in detail what applications you are trying to get to cooperate in what manner, and *why* do you think you need two IP addresses for PC A.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what are you trying to accomplish, since 10.49.1.1 and 10.49.1.8 can talk each other in the same subnet. 
The switch works at layer 2, so 10.70.70.1 might be an ip address solely for the purpose of management, and is not involved in the communication at Layer 3.
Just plug PC A and PC B into two ports of the switch in the same VLAN (untagged), and it works.
.: Francesco

Comment: The default broadcast range for 10.x.x.x is 10.0.0.0/8, so anything with address 10.* is mutually on-link.

Comment: My question is clear, there exist two PCs, which are in the same subnet, but they shall also send and receive packets via different IP address. I know it make no sense but, if I add 10.75.75.1 to PC B I cant reach this IP Address from PC A.

Comment: @countermode Thanks for the hint, I will check it! So, adding 10.0.0.0/8 as gateway to PC A and PC B will solve it?

Comment: 10.0.0.0/8 is a network segment, not an ip address. You want put 10.70.70.1 as gateway for the destination ip address on both PC, but this won't work. If they are in the same subnet (10.0.0.0/8), still the host will not go through a gateway.